# Why can't I push an empty commit?

Tags: git

```
  git commit --amend --allow-empty
```

then

```
  git push origin master
```

the git said that

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'remoteurl'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Why? How to fix this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The issue is not that you are pushing an *empty* commit.
It is about pushing a *different* commit (one with a different SHA1) than the one commit already pushed.
That is what `git commit --amend` does: it modified the last commit, it doesn't create a new one.

That means you are pushing a *different* history than the one others might have already cloned.
If you are sure that won't be a problem, you need to force the push:

```
git push -f origin master
```

Should you have done:

```
git commit --allow-empty
```

You would have created a *new* (empty) commit, which you could have pushed without any issue.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create pull request on Github. You can:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "make pull request"
```

Then create pull request with no change.

Answer (score 4):

To clarify the accepted answer, since I don't have enough reputation to comment:

When you use

```
git commit --amend
```

it *does* create a new commit.  However, it doesn't append it to the current commit, it appends it to the parent of the current commit.  Visually, it would look like a fork.

```
  O (old commit)
 /
O-O (amended commit)
```

Git interprets this as a divergence from the remote.  That is why it will not let you push it without forcing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the remote branch you are trying to push to isn't currently checked out. I made a git repository on one of my servers once and couldn't figure out why I couldn't push to it. After a day or so of troubleshooting, I found out that I couldn't push to the repository (or the branch I wanted to) while it was checked out on the server repository. So, I simply made a new branch that I checkout when I'm done making changes on the server, and I can then push to the server. This might not be your issue, but I was getting an error similar to this when I had an issue pushing to an empty git on my server.